# Как преобразовать строку serialize в Json или массив?

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, сериализация

Всем привет, на Laravel пробую отправить форму в контроллер с помощью JQ через Ajax. В контроллере получаю Request. Отправляю _token и поля формы с помощью метода serialize(). Проверил выводом из контроллера в console.log(data) приходят данные из формы в формате: "par1=1&par2=2&par3=&par4=23...", соответственно это строка, похожая на результат GET запроса... но обратиться к элементам я не могу (вероятно, что это строка), вот и возник вопрос, как эту строку преобразовать в Array или JSON? Подскажите пожалуйста, может даже ссылку, уже много чего перечитал и попробовал, не работало...

Answer (score 1):

Например можно сперва разбить на массив по `&`, таким образом

```js
let arr = "par1=1&par2=2&par3=3&par4=23".split('&')
console.log(arr); // ['par1=1', 'par2=2', 'par3=3', 'par4=23']
```

Далее можно разбить по знаку `=`, получится так

```js
let arr = "par1=1&par2=2&par3=3&par4=23".split('&')
let arrNew = arr.map(el => el.split('='))
console.log(arrNew); // [Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2)]
```